# Query empty if included

Tags: php, mysql

I have been performing a query inside my page -- say, page.php -- where I run a simple query.

*Pseudo-code:*

```
$request_unavailble = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE availble='0'");
```

When this is performed from within page.php, I get all results where availble is set to 0. However, if I run this from within a seperate included file, the data returns empty. In fact, `mysqli_num_rows` returns 0 when included.

What's going wrong, here?

---

#### Edit

The following function was added as an include (both as a function and alone)

```
function compte_messagerie()
{
    $requetes_messagerie = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."messagerie WHERE lu='0'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($requetes_messagerie) == 0)
    {
        echo '<a id="messagerie" href="messagerie">'.AUCUN_NOUVEAU."</a>";
    }
    else if(mysqli_num_rows($requetes_messagerie) == 1)
    {
        echo '<a id="messagerie" href="messagerie">';
        echo '<span>'.mysqli_num_rows($requetes_messagerie)."</span> ";
        echo MESSAGES_SINGULIER."</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a id="messagerie" href="messagerie">';
        echo '<span>'.mysqli_num_rows($requetes_messagerie)."</span> ";
        echo MESSAGES_PLURIEL."</a>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Post more code. If it behaves differently inside an include, it could be something like variable scope tripping you up. Do you have error reporting turned up?  `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Yes, error reporting is always turned on. I've also added the code, as requested.

Comment: As I suspected - `$mysqli` is not in scope inside that functoin.  Your query fails, but you don't check errors on it.  Do you not see something like `mysqli_query expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given`?

Comment: Should I place this inside my class which _does_ include my global $db variable (including $mysqli) ?

Comment: Put it where it makes sense organizationally.  You need to get `$mysqli` into it though - I recommend passing it as a param `function compte_messagerie($mysqli) {...}`

Comment: Passing $mysqli as a parameter does make it clean and simple. For the record, this worked as expected. Would you please consider adding this solution (and perhaps previous explanations) for future references by other users? I will mark it as accepted. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ok, I added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When porting your query into a function, the MySQLi connection object in `$mysqli` went out of scope, and was therefore invalid inside the function.  With `display_errors` enabled, I would expect you to see errors like:

> Notice: undefined variable $mysqli
>
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given

The cleanest solution is to pass `$mysqli` into your function as a parameter, making it available to the function's scope

```
// Expect the MySQLi resource as a parameter...
function compte_messagerie($mysqli)
{
    $requetes_messagerie = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM ".DB_PREFIX."messagerie WHERE lu='0'");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($requetes_messagerie) == 0)
    {
        echo '<a id="messagerie" href="messagerie">'.AUCUN_NOUVEAU."</a>";
    }
    // etc.....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Please check if the available table is require string value or integer.

```
$request_unavailble = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE availble= 0 ");

while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($request_unavailble)){ // <- this will check if there some data fetch

  // You put some code here
  }
```